# How to realize string manipulation?

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7

I've got some string value in input, something like this :

```
hellOWOrLD.hELLOWORLD.
```

in the output i need :

```
Helloworld. Helloworld.
```

Or in input :

```
A.B.A.C.A.B.A.
```

and output :

```
A. B. A. C. A. B. A.
```

So as you see i need words separeted by dot.
Also the rules of task is that if input can't be modifed output will be 1.

So i tried to do like this:

```
import sys
input = raw_input().lower().split('.')

for el in input:
    sys.stdout.write(el.capitalize() + '.',)
```

So this ain't good code. Can you help me?

Comment: What do you mean by "ain't good code"? See how to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way using `re.sub` and a if statement to check:

```
import re
usrinput = raw_input()
pretty = " ".join([x.capitalize() for x in re.sub('\.','. ', usrinput.lower()).split()]).strip()
if pretty == usrinput:
    print 1
else:
    print pretty
```

Input:

```
hellOWOrLD.hELLOWORLD.
```

Output:

```
Helloworld. Helloworld.
```

Input2:

```
A.B.A.C.A.B.A.
```

Output2:

```
A. B. A. C. A. B. A.
```

Input3:

```
Helloworld. Helloworld.
```

Output3:

```
1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way that seems to work:

```
input = # get input from somewhere
output = '. '.join([ piece.capitalize() for piece in input.split('.') ])
```

E.g. If `input` is `"hellOWOrLD.hELLOWORLD."`, `output` is `"Helloworld. Helloworld. "`.

If you want to get rid of the final space, use:

```
output = output.strip(' ')
```

If you want `output` to be `1` in the case that no change was made, do this:

```
if input == output:
    output = 1
```

Comment: Please fix your code. The second code block isn't formatted properly and the last line isn't valid python

Comment: trim()? may be rstrip()

Comment: @dementedhegehog there's still one more complaint, trim isn't a valid method for strings, this answer needs to either be deleted or get fixed by the answerer

Comment: Sorry y'all, had some javascript rattling around in my head as I wrote this.